# How to wait for all tasks within a ThreadPoolExecutor to finish within a timeout and without shutting the Executor down?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

After using a ThreadPoolExecutor to manage my tasks instead of creating for each of one a separate thread. I used the following part to wait for a specific amount of tasks to finish:

```
poolThreadsExecutor.shutdown();
poolThreadsExecutor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
for (Future<List<String>> future : futures) {
    if (!future.isDone()) {
       future.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

With this code I made sure no new tasks could be submitted until the ones running are finished. There is also a timeout for the running tasks and afterwards I check the futures list and cancel any task in case it is blocked.

With this solution I have all the points I want, but the problem is that the executor will be destroyed afterwards and I have to create a new one each time.

Is there a possibility to get the same function without shutting down the executor ?

P.S.: I also can't use the CoundDownLatch because the number of tasks are not known before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be an outline of a solution:

1. calculate the deadline for task completion: `deadline = currentTimeMillis() + timeout`;
2. loop through all the futures, calling `future.get(timeLeft, MILLISECONDS)`, each time adjusting `timeLeft = deadline - currentTimeMillis()`;
3. if the deadline is reached, then break out of this loop and go into the cancellation loop.

---

```
final long deadline = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
for (Future<?> f : futures) {
  final long timeLeft = deadline - System.currentTimeMillis();
  if (timeLeft <= 0) break;
  try {
    f.get(timeLeft, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  } catch (TimeoutException e) {
     break;
  }
}

for (Future<?> f : futures) {
  if (!future.isDone()) {
     future.cancel(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I modified the code to fulfill my needs. So now it looks like:  `for (Future<?> f : futures) {
            try {
              f.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);            
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.warn("Error occured ...: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
          }

          for (Future<?> f : futures) {
            if (!future.isDone()) {
               future.cancel(true);
            }
          }`

Comment: So you left out `break;` from the catch-block? It works without it, but I would not leave it out.

Comment: First I wrote `continue;` instead, but because no code is written after, it is wasn't necessary. I left out `break;` in order to get the results from the other tasks. Now each task becomes a "smaller" timeout in which it should finish its computing, and in case one is blocked or throws another exception a logging message will be written and the I try to get the result from the next task. At the end I cancel all the blocked tasks if any.

Comment: I see, you want to log all exceptions, even after the timeout.

Comment: I have another small issue now by trying to provide a poolname. Is it possible to set a poolname without using other libraries (e.g. com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder) ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you submit your tasks. But I see that you have a list of futures.
If you can submit all tasks at once you can use:

```
futures = poolThreadsExecutor.invokeAll(tasks, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

It will execute your tasks, blocking until all complete or the timeout expires (tasks that have not completed are cancelled).

Also [Futures.successfulAsList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#successfulAsList(java.lang.Iterable)) from guava may be helpful.

Comment: I think OP's note that the number of futures is not known in advance precludes this.

Comment: As Marko mentioned. The number of the tasks are not known before. When one is created I submit it with the function:   `poolThreadsExecutor.submit(task)` and I save the return value in a list that I process later.